# Django TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'dict'

Tags: python, django

I made a base model.
And I want to inherit it and makemigrations  model.
But I catch an error. I don't understand the cause.
I want you to tell me if you understand.

```
    from apps.models.casts.casts import Cast
  File "/Users/t.a/Desktop/apasn/apasn_rest/apasn_back/apps/models/casts/casts.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Cast(AbstractModel):
  File "/Users/t.a/Desktop/apasn/apasn_rest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 273, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, new_field)
  File "/Users/t.a/Desktop/apasn/apasn_rest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/t.a/Desktop/apasn/apasn_rest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 735, in contribute_to_class
    super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=private_only, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.a/Desktop/apasn/apasn_rest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 304, in contribute_to_class
    'app_label': cls._meta.app_label.lower()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'dict'
```

Abstract model

```
from django.db import models
from apps.models.commons import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import uuid


class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='created_user', editable=False)
    updated_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='updated_user')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

```
from django.db import models
from apps.models.commons.accounts import User
from apps.utils.models.abstract import AbstractModel
from apps.utils.models.region import CityModel
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Cast(AbstractModel):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cast'

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    establishment = models.DateField(_('establishment'), blank=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you've done in your code? `related_name = ('created_user',)` because of the `,`, Python interpreted it as tuple, however it supposed to be string

Comment: I did it.
Thank you very much.
It was insufficient confirmation.